# mysql query - Find element A that contains all of element B

Tags: mysql

Dilemma: This query achieves "Find all drinkers that like at least one beer sold by Caravan"

The "IN" keyword acts like a massive OR statement.

The goal query is: Find drinkers who like EVERY beer served by Caravan

```
SELECT drinker 
FROM BarBeerDrinker.likes
WHERE BarBeerDrinker.likes.beer IN (
        SELECT beer
        FROM BarBeerDrinker.sells
        WHERE BarBeerDrinker.sells.bar = "Caravan"
    );
```

Schema:

**Likes table**

```
     drinker    beer
     John   "Blue Moon"
     Mike   "Blue Moon"
     John   “Budweiser”
     Mike   “Budweiser”
     John   "Creamy Dark"
     Mike   "Creamy Dark"
     Mike   “Hefeweizen”
     John   “Killian's”
     John   "Michelob Golden Draft"
     Mike   "Michelob Golden Draft Light"
     John   "Original Premium"
     Mike   "Original Premium Lager"
     Jesse  "Original Premium Lager Dog"
     Mike   "Original Premium Lager Dog"
     John   "Stolichnaya Citrona"
```

---

**Sells Table**

```
   bar  beer
   "A.P. Stump's"   Hefeweizen
   "Blue Angel" "Hefeweizen Doppelbock"
   "Blue Angel" "Original Premium Lager Dog"
   "Blue Tattoo"    Killian's
   "Britannia Arms" Budweiser
   Cabana   Budweiser
   Caravan  Budweiser
   Caravan  "Original Premium Lager Dog"
   .
   .
   .
```

**Expected Output:**
Mike

Comment: You can use `EXCEPT/MINUS`  and `NOT EXISTS` to check it. For example `WHERE NOT EXISTS (all _beers from Caravan MINUS all beers liked by drinker)` If drinker likes all beers the difference will be empty result set

Comment: show the schema with `show create table likes` and `show create table sells` ... this right way to show it

Comment: that is not schema that is data sample

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be useful , please do not vote down if it's not ( or if i misspeleed anything )
( aliases may require AS keyword , depends on db type )

```
select count(*), drinker from (
select  a.drinker, b.beer 
    FROM BarBeerDrinker.likes a , BarBeerDrinker.likes b
     where a.beer = b.beer and b.bar = 'Caravan'
   group by a.drinker, b.beer )
group by drinker
   having count(*) = ( select count(*) from BarBeerDrinker.likes c where c.bar = 'Caravan' )
```

Answer (score 0):

First get to know NOT(Likes) = (Likes X Likes) - Likes 

This will give me 'notlikes' table which records of drinker who do not like particular beer.

`notlikes = select a.drinker, b.beer
           from Likes a join Likes b
           MINUS
           select l.drinker, l.beer
           from Likes l` 

Now get list of drinkers who don't like all the drinks served/sold by Caravan

`notanswer = select notlikes.drinker
            from notlikes, Sells
            where notlikes.beer = Sells.beer and Sells.bar = 'Caravan'`

Get entire list of drinkers who drinks some beer at Caravan

`drinkers = select l.drinker
           from Likes l join Sells s
           where l.beer = s.beer and s.bar = 'Caravan';` 


To get answer, subtract notanswer from drinkers

 `answer = drinkers - notanswer;`

Answer (score 0):

I would go other way:

At 1st I search for all beers at caravan (caravanbeer), then i OUTER JOIN only those caravanbeers with all likes - but i am only interested in those whose likes i can't join - they are NULL. Then i take all people who are not in this result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT likes.drinker FROM likes WHERE likes.drinker NOT IN (
SELECT likes.drinker FROM (
SELECT * FROM sells WHERE sells.bar = 'Caravan') AS caravanbeer 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN likes ON likes.beer = caravanbeer.beer 
WHERE caravanbeer.bar IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a066b/2

I did some changes in data sample provided to demonstarte that query works in different  combination of data values, so in my case query return `Jessy` and `Mike` according my data.

```
SELECT l.drinker,  s.s_count
FROM sells
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT bar, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT beer) s_count
  FROM sells
  GROUP BY bar
  ) s
on sells.bar = s.bar
LEFT JOIN likes l
ON l.beer = sells.beer
WHERE s.bar = "Caravan"
GROUP BY drinker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.beer) = s.s_count
```